# Is it possible to align one point cloud with another while keeping one point fixed?

Tags: python, 3d, computer-vision, alignment, point-clouds

I have two similar, but not identical, roughly cylindrical pointclouds.

Currently, to align them I roughly align their major axes (method unimportant for this question) and then use open3d's ICP to fine tune the fit.

Is it possible for me to do some sort of alignment where I first set one point from each pointcloud (the end of the major axes in this case) to the same location and then align the rest of the points in the pointcloud, keeping those aligned endpoints the same? I tried to demonstrate the concept in the attached image.[image: description of concept]

Comment: sounds like ICP with an additional constraint

Answer (score 0):

If the two point clouds are similar:

1. Align the mass center of the 2nd PC to that of the 1st PC (initial position values)
2. Perform PCA to both PCs
3. Take the 3 possibilities of axis-alignment between the two PCs as the initial orinetation values for ICA.

Of course, the expected result is not guaranteed.

The above 1-3 steps are eqivalent to the steps of:
"Least-Squares Fitting of Two 3-D Point Sets",
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4767965